# Script for locating "Service" locations in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, cacls

I am trying to write a script in windows command prompt (windows 8), to find out the directory location of services running. For example

```
net start // gives all the running services. I want to know the location of those services
```

Help required!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command is using PowerShell in order to display what you want:

```
powershell.exe -noexit "Get-WmiObject win32_service | select Name, DisplayName, State, PathName"
```

Just copy and paste it into a "cmd" window.
It will display you the service name, the display name, the state and the path to the executable.

Comment: Works like a charm! thanks, is there any command for non power shell cmd?@Patrick

Comment: PowerShell is the easiest way. I doubt that there is a way to approach this with a single "cmd" command.